# Custom validation Error Messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I am working with dataannotations and I have applied a range validator but the error message in the validator is not working. It is defaulted to "The Code1 field is required" ..

```
View Page::

  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Code1, Model.Codes, "Select", new { })
                      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(mbox => mbox.Code1)

model
  [Range(1, 250, ErrorMessage = "code field is required")]
        public int Code1 { get; set; }
```

I do not know why my defined error message is not showing up.

I have also tried in changing the message in view page:

```
View Page::

  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Code1, Model.Codes1, "Select","Code is required", new { })
```

Now, the message defined here is working but it is giving me a weird behaviour.
It shows the above given message in black and white and just changes to red when the 
Validation fires and when I change a value in dropdown it again becomes black and white.

enter code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the required validator instead of the range validator for compulsory entry.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Code1 is required")]
    [Range(1, 250, ErrorMessage = "Value must be between 1 and 250")]
    public int Code1 { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can additionally also use the Range validator, but use the one above and confirm that it is working.

Comment: that's Working but why range is not working. I use to apply range in MVC3 and it worked  every time.

Comment: That is what I mentioned,you can use range too.Try this-[Required(ErrorMessage = "Code must be set")]
[Range(1, 250, ErrorMessage = "Code must be between 1 and 250")]
public int Code1{ get; set; }

Comment: one thing I do not know but please answer me . I have written @Html.validationmessagefor(m=>m.code). But if I remove required and even range validator from model, then also validation message shows up and says field code1 is required.

Comment: IMHO there is no way for a validation to occur without setting it up first,so copy the message string,search in the project for the string and see where it is coming from.